# CKEDITOR - List every element in a selection (to get the computed style of childless elements)?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

This sounds straightforward but turns out to be extremely obscure.

I'd like to show the foreground or background color of the current selected elements, if they all share the same one.  So if the user has selected the text "asdf", where "as" is underlined and "df" isn't, I'd be able to figure out that all the selected text is still red.

If I had a simple array of every element included in the current selection in the editor, then I could at least check each to see if they have any children, and if not, call getComputedStyle on them.  I think.

But I can't figure out any way to get a list of elements included in a selection.

I've played with nodes, walkers, iterators, elementpaths, blocks or something, and a number of other approaches.  Nothing in the CKEDITOR API is jumping out at me as a solution to this.

Am I missing something obvious, or can anyone suggest a not-so-obvious approach?

Thanks!

Update: Reinmar's advice was helpful, but I abandoned the effort before I could get it working.  I decided that it was actually more user friendly, in the case of selections with multiple colors, to use the starting color rather than no color.  Then give the user a way to replace the entire selection with that color if they like.  It's friendly, usable, and simple.

Comment: The short answer is selection->range->walker. Walker will give you every node in a range.

Comment: That was my thought too, but nodes appear to be internal representations of DOM elements rather than something I can call getComputedStyle on.  I also tried node.$ and a few other things.

Comment: You get [`CKEDITOR.dom.node`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.node), so you can either access `node.$` or use CKEditor's [`CKEDITOR.dom.element.getComputedStyle`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.element-method-getComputedStyle).

Comment: I'd tried those but didn't have much luck.  In any event, I decided to try using the first color only, and that actually turned out very user friendly and intuitive, probably moreso than if I'd gotten this approach to work.  Thank you anyway for your help, Reinmar, it was a hard weekend and it was comforting to know I wasn't alone on this!